# creating a Directory tree structure on a JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I recently came across the Java DefaultMutableTreeNode class. I was wondering if there is any similar classes/technology available for Servlets/JSPs.

I am working on a web application for which a database table stores absolute path name for various files, my servlet is supposed to read the path names from the table and display them as a directory tree structure.

Thanks so much in advance. Any advise will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you use a jQuery plugin to display your paths as a tree?

https://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree

> jQuery File Tree is a configurable, AJAX file browser plugin for jQuery. You can create a customized, fully-interactive file tree with as little as one line of JavaScript code.

Comment: Note that this still requires a (homegrown?) tree structure at the server side... jQuery is purely for presentation part.

Answer (score 1):

Not out the box. You have to create it yourself or to head to a 3rd party taglib or framework.

Several examples:

- [A 3rd party JSP taglib](http://jsptree.sourceforge.net/)
- [A tag of the Struts2 framework](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/tree.html)
- [A tag of a 3rd party JSF component library](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_tree.html)
- [A tag of another 3rd party JSF component library](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tree.jsf)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a web application framework, you may also consider the Tree-component from [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com). See the [Sampler](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/) for a Tree example, including source code.