# Displaying files and folder in jsp using hyperlink

Tags: java, file, jsp

I want to access files and folder from a directory say "c:/Test/Example/NewExample.pdf".
I want to dynamically create a jsp page which lists all the folders from the root folder. Once i click on any folder it show its content ans so on. Its  a tree like structure but with hyperlinks.

I get the data using the recursive function to get folder contents but i am not able to generate the jsp dynamically.

```
  public void listDirectory(String dirPath, int level) {
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] firstLevelFiles = dir.listFiles();
    if (firstLevelFiles != null && firstLevelFiles.length > 0) {
        for (File aFile : firstLevelFiles) {
            for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("[" + aFile.getName() + "]");

                listDirectory(aFile.getAbsolutePath(), level + 1);
            } else {
                System.out.println(aFile.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what i have done to list the data. i added the ordered list and href tag to show it in a list format.but this gives me the data till the first level only. dirPath is the path from where i want the data. now once i write this code inside jsp page i have to use scriptlet. now as this is a recursive function i have to call the same function again which is been declared in the jsp itself. now when i add the list tag for this declared method this gives error.

This is what i have done till now. If i want to browse the folder how can i do that. This prints the contents of the directory and i am able to access the files but i need to access the folders also

```
try {
                File currentDir = new File("path to my directory inside project"); // current directory
                //File currentDir = new File("C:/Users/NehaSingh/Desktop/imp");
                System.out.println("     currentDir:" + currentDir.getCanonicalPath());
                System.out.println("     currentDir:" + currentDir.getAbsolutePath());

                File[] files = currentDir.listFiles();
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                        String fn=file.getCanonicalPath();
                        String fnList[]=fn.split("WebContent");
                        String b="";
                        for(int i=0;i<fnList.length;i++)
                        {
                             b=fnList[i];
                            System.out.println("     b:" + b);

                        }
                        %>
                        <h2>b: <%=b %></h2>
                        <a href="./<%=b%>"><%=file.getName()%></a>
                        <%
                        //displayDirectoryContents(file);
                    } else {
                        String fn=file.getCanonicalPath();
                        String fnList[]=fn.split("WebContent");
                        String c="";
                        for(int i=0;i<fnList.length;i++)
                        {
                             c=fnList[i];
                            System.out.println("     c:" + c);

                        }
                        System.out.println("     file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                        %>
                        <h2>c: <%=c %></h2>
                        <a href="./<%=c%>"><%=file.getName()%></a>

                        <%
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        %>
```

Comment: What did you try, what issue do you have? What do you mean by "generate the jsp dynamically"??

Comment: [link]https://librarian.outernet.is/en/files/  i want the structure to be like this

Comment: OK, so now we know, what you want to achieve. Now show us, what you have tried. SO is not for offering complete solutions, but for helping with specific problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008521/creating-a-directory-tree-structure-on-a-jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008521/creating-a-directory-tree-structure-on-a-jsp).

Comment: @Rishal dev singh You redirect to the question, having the accepted answer with the not-existing link. Please be more thorough.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis for existing link[https://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree) and demo check the link[http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/). I think its now having complete details.

Comment: @Rishal dev singh This is a tree structured format. i need to show it jsp using hyperlinks. i have already gone through all this. 
[link]librarian.outernet.is/en/files   see this link. this i what i need

Comment: So you posted your requirements and now ask us to do the job? You know that developer is a paid job, don't you? So my advice is, write down your requirements and find some professional **or** if you are the developer, ask for some specific *programming* issue you are facing (and post your related code)

Comment: @RC. I am not telling you to do it for me. I am just asking for a way to do it. Thanks for your help.